# Is this user a SpamBot?

Tags: support, users

Is this [user](https://superuser.com/users/38742/samsol) a Spambot? ~10 questions in a span of about 5 minutes o_0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I can say that I'm not spammer. And 'SamSol' is combination of my name and my surname.

I posted those questions that I could not find answers to from my 10 years of study and research.  I always have innovative questions. Currently I'm an iPhone developer. Don't doubt about me. I'm always helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like quack was very diligently retagging them (damn, good work quickly) and then noticed they were all from the same user... Yeah, it looks questionable to me, too.

Were the questions simply copy-pasted from another forum?  If so, we should definitely discourage that, even though it'd probably be okay if they were instead posted at a rate of 1/day instead of 1/30sec.

The display name says it all:

### SamSol

"ol" is a "p" spun around and separated.

### SamSp

Now place the 5th letter before the 2nd (those being the first and third prime numbers).

### Spams

And if you add up all the digits using hexavigesimal, you get 666...

Comment: Talk about astute analysis o_0

Comment: @ess: You can make [anything line up with anything else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology).  For example, I see two different ways to connect this to 42.

Comment: 1st of all, I say that I m not spammer. and 'SamSol' is combination of my name and my surname.  I posted those questions that I could not find from my 10 years study and research.  I always hav innovative question. currently I m iphone developer.  dont doubt abt me. I m always helpful.

Comment: @Sam: The bit about your username was simple fun that no one should have taken seriously.  Ten questions in 5 minutes *is* questionable, which the serious part of my answer is about.

Comment: @gnome- oh yeh it's also. but that's my speed unfortunately. It's not spamming practise. now I take carf abt that...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, he does has comments and downvote (revoked, but from badge), accepted answers on stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/351784?tab=activity#tab-top

Comment: Same pattern on SO, plenty of questions asked in a row. Maybe it's legitimate, he was simply very curious about a lot of things. But it looks strange to have so many questions at same time.

Comment: @Gnoupi, Yeah, could be sock puppets or just spammer, but I wanted to say that he do more than a bot.

Comment: @Mark - As @Gnoupi mentioned, the timing (or the lack of any time difference) is what made/makes me suspicious

Comment: 1st of all, I say that I m not spammer. and 'SamSol' is combination of my name and my surname.  I posted those questions that I could not find from my 10 years study and research.  I always hav innovative question. currently I m iphone developer.  dont doubt abt me. I m always helpful.